# Rolling up multiple rows into single row using 2 tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is there any way to change a SQL query that would normally return multiple rows with the same values into a single row as comma separated?

```
Table1
------
Col1
------
Sci-Fi
Action
Crime

Table2
------------
Col1 | Col2
------------
1    | Action
1    | Sci-Fi
2    | Crime
2    | Action
2    | Sci-Fi
```

And I need a query that results like this:
(Table1 and Table2 combined)

```
----------------------------
Col1 |  Col2
----------------------------
1    | Action, Sci-Fi
2    | Crime, Action, Sci-Fi
```

Comment: I don't understand - what does the first table have to do with the second?  Why is it even needed?

Comment: use PIVOT https://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/194852/concatenate-many-rows-into-a-single-text-string

Comment: Table1 contains much more data like: genre_description etc. I can use this 'Table1' in the future to add genre's to 'new' movies

Comment: Look into using the STUFF command in conjunction with FOR XML. Plenty of examples online.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`SELECT MG.movie_id
, STUFF(( 
    SELECT ',' + G.genre_name 
    FROM    Movie_Genre AS G 
    WHERE   G.movie_id = MG.movie_id 
    ORDER BY    G.genre_name FOR XML PATH('') ), 1, 1, '') AS Genres 
FROM Movie_Genre AS MG 
GROUP BY MG.movie_id`

Credit to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/273238/how-to-use-group-by-to-concatenate-strings-in-sql-server) for the crazy awesome STUFF expression.

Comment: I'm getting this error: Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'Action' to data type int.

Comment: Ah, your WHERE G.genre_name = MG.movie_id is not going to work because you are comparing an int to a varchar.  You don't need table 1 at all. Only table 2 should be referenced and change the where clause to WHERE G.movie_id = NG.movie_id

Comment: Fixed your query: SELECT MG.movie_id
, STUFF(( 
 SELECT ',' + G.genre_name 
 FROM Movie_Genre AS G 
 WHERE G.movie_id = MG.movie_id 
 ORDER BY G.genre_name FOR XML PATH('') ), 1, 1, '') AS Genres 
FROM Movie_Genre AS MG 
GROUP BY MG.movie_id

Comment: TY user1499246, could you edit you're answer to this query? I accept when you do it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [STUFF](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188043.aspx) function to combine multiple row as comma separated.

[Sample SQl Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6eb3c/2)

```
SELECT ID, col2 =
            stuff((
                   SELECT ','+ [col2] FROM t WHERE Id = t1.Id FOR XML PATH('')
                  ),1,1,'') 
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT ID FROM t ) t1
```

[Refer Here for More](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194852/concatenate-many-rows-into-a-single-text-string)

Comment: I'm getting this error: Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'Action' to data type int.

Comment: SELECT MG.movie_id,
         STUFF((
      SELECT      ',' + G.genre_name
               FROM   Genre AS G
               WHERE  G.genre_name = MG.movie_id
      ORDER BY  G.genre_name
               FOR XML PATH('')
     ), 1, 1, '') AS Genres
FROM      Movie_Genre AS MG
GROUP BY MG.movie_id

Comment: which table is Genre Or Movie_Genre  in your Question?