# Rolling up multiple rows in single row

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am trying to merge rows of employee DB table

Here is my original table

[image]

I want to merge rows based on department. here is my expected result.

[image]

I tried using  FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '') but I canroll up only one column.

I know we have similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30604252/rolling-up-multiple-rows-into-single-row-using-2-tables) but its rolling up only one column.

any help is much appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use the same method for the other columns:

```
SELECT
    t.Department,
    Worker = 
        STUFF((
            SELECT ';' + Worker
            FROM tbl 
            WHERE Department = t.Department
            ORDER BY Worker
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
        ).value('text()[1]','NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, N''),
    Phone = 
        STUFF((
            SELECT ';' + Phone
            FROM tbl 
            WHERE Department = t.Department
            ORDER BY Worker
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
        ).value('text()[1]','NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, N''),
    Ext = 
        STUFF((
            SELECT ';' + Ext
            FROM tbl 
            WHERE Department = t.Department
            ORDER BY Worker
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
        ).value('text()[1]','NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, N'')
FROM tbl t
GROUP BY t.Department
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try the query below:

```
SELECT
    t.Department,
    Worker = STUFF((
                SELECT ';' + s.Worker
                FROM
                    YourTable s
                WHERE
                    s.Department = t.Department
                FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,''),
    Phone = STUFF((
                SELECT ';' + CAST(s.Phone AS VARCHAR(25))
                FROM
                    YourTable s
                WHERE
                    s.Department = t.Department
                FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,''),
    Ext = STUFF((
                SELECT ';' + CAST(s.Ext AS VARCHAR(25))
                FROM
                    YourTable s
                WHERE
                    s.Department = t.Department
                FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'')
FROM YourTable t
GROUP BY t.Department
```

Answer (score 0):

I just found this online a couple days ago.  I tried it and it worked great for me.  Give it a go and see how you get along.

http://groupconcat.codeplex.com/

http://groupconcat.codeplex.com/releases/view/618110

Create TABLE  testtable(
    Customer VARCHAR(50),
    Product VARCHAR(50),
    Method VARCHAR(50),
    INDEX ix CLUSTERED (Customer)
)

INSERT INTO testtable (Customer, Product, Method)
VALUES
    ('John', 'Computer', 'Credit'),
    ('John', 'Mouse', 'Cash'),
    ('Will', 'Computer', 'Credit'),
    ('Will', 'Mouse', 'Cash'),
    ('Will', 'Speaker', 'Cash'),
    ('Todd', 'Computer', 'Credit')

Select *
From testtable

SELECT Customer,dbo.GROUP_CONCAT(product),dbo.GROUP_CONCAT(method)
FROM testtable
GROUP BY Customer

[image]